# Pass Options into Common Autocomplete Component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm making a common autocomplete component in Angular. I'm also using Angular Material.
I am on v15, but I'm NOT using MDC, so I guess I'm using v14 material components.

I need to be able to pass mat-options into this common autocomplete component.
Right now, I have this working, except for keyboard functions. The options being given to the common component are appearing in the autocomplete popup, but I can't use the arrow keys to navigate through them (like you usually can). The arrow keys only work for the options already in the common component.

Check out this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/57thbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftest-autocomplete%2Ftest-autocomplete.component.html

Is there a way to achieve this? I'm confused on why keyboard controls wouldn't be working since the DOM is rendering the mat-options being given the same as those in the common component.

Also, I cannot simply take in a string array input and use it in the template for options, because I want to be able to take in different things. For example, a mat-option could simply be:
`<mat-option>Option</mat-option>` or it could be:

```
<mat-option [value]="row.memberName" mat-option class="custom-styling">
  <span class="custom-styling">
    <span class="custom-span flex-1">{{ row.memberName }}</span>
    <span class="custom-span w-1000">{{ row.dob | date: "MM/dd/yyyy" }}</span>
    <span class="custom-span flex-1">{{ row.memberCode }}</span>
    <span class="custom-span flex-1">{{ row.businessLine }}</span>
    <span class="custom-span flex-1">{{ row.businessUnit }}</span>
  </span>
</mat-option>
```

That's why an array input won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is a directive + *ngTemplateOutlet

At first the directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTestAutocompleteOption]',
})
export class TestAutocompleteOptionDirective {
  constructor(public template: TemplateRef<unknown>) {}
}
```

Then your autocomplete component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'test-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: 'test-autocomplete.component.html',
})
export class TestAutocompleteComponent {
  protected queryList$ = new ReplaySubject<
    QueryList<TestAutocompleteOptionDirective>
  >(1);

  @ContentChildren(TestAutocompleteOptionDirective)
  set queryListOfOptions(value: QueryList<TestAutocompleteOptionDirective>) {
    this.queryList$.next(value);
  }
}
```

You will need to use a replaysubject because the query list is available after ngContentInit

Then use this template for the autocomplete component

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="queryList$ | async as queryList">
  <input matInput type="search" [matAutocomplete]="autocomplete" />
  <mat-icon matPrefix>search</mat-icon>
  <mat-autocomplete #autocomplete="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option>start</mat-option>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let option of queryList">
      <mat-option>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="option.template"></ng-container>
      </mat-option>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-option>end</mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
```

Notice the ngFor over each element in the QueryList (which contains all Directive-Objects)

And then use it like this:

```
<test-autocomplete>
  <ng-template appTestAutocompleteOption *ngFor="let row of [1, 2, 3]">
    given option {{row +1}}
  </ng-template>
</test-autocomplete>
```

Now you have successfully projected the content into your view.

Here is a complete example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/57thbg-rjzbcn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-filter-example.html

Comment: This works really well and fixes the keyboard arrow issue. TY :)  But, how would we set the value of the option? So that the correct value is sent when an option is selected.

Comment: give the directive an @Input() and use it in your autocomplete component like you used the template

Comment: ✨amazing✨! Thanks.